# How to resolve Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset" error

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild, dotnet-cli, dotnet-build

Thanks in Advance, your help is greatly appreciated!

I am using this **code** `dotnet build E:\abc\abc.sln /p:Congiguration=Release` but it's giving error below error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(135,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset".

This ruleset ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset file call from **Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets** files.

I see the code of target file line number 135 as below:

```
<ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet
CodeAnalysisRuleSet="$(CodeAnalysisRuleSet)"
CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories="$(CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories)"
MSBuildProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
<Output TaskParameter="ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet" PropertyName="ResolvedCodeAnalysisRuleSet" />
</ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

I  have manually paste ruleset file but still doesn't work and Please explain me how to get CodeAnalysisRuleSet , CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories path from target file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interrogate build-time property values, add `-bl` to your `dotnet build` command, install [MSBuild Structured/Binary Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) and use it to open the `msbuild.binlog` file in the solution directory. You can then search for `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` to find the point(s) during the build when values were assigned to the `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` and `CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories` properties.

Update: Also see [Troubleshoot and create logs for MSBuild problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/msbuild-logs) in the Visual Studio documentation.

Comment: this is 3rd party tool, Is this any official available for the same?

Comment: It's maintained by a Microsoft employee and is open-source. I have not looked for others.

Comment: update: Microsoft's documentation also references it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/msbuild-logs?view=vs-2019 _"You can view and search your .binlog files by using the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://www.msbuildlog.com/)."_